# Page redirect After Update data with custom code in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have put a WordPress code to change the profile. The data is being updated, but after updating it is not redirected to the main page. Now I have to redirect it to another page if it gets redirected, then data not update.  How could I do that?

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="profile-field">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>                                     
        <!--tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $user_details['first_name'][0]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><?php echo wp_get_current_user()->user_email;?></td>
        </tr-->
        <p class="form-username">
            <label for="first-name"><?php _e('First Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
            <input class="text-input" name="first-name" type="text" id="first-name"
                   value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p class="form-username">
            <label for="last-name"><?php _e('User mail', 'profile'); ?></label>
            <input class="text-input" name="last-name" type="text" id="last-name"
                   value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <!--tr>
            <td>Company Code</td>
            <td><?php echo $user_details['companycode'][0]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Industry</td>
            <td><?php echo $user_details['industury'][0]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Job title</td>
            <td><?php echo $user_details['jobtitle'][0]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Experience</td>
            <td><?php echo $user_details['experience'][0]; ?> Years</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table-->
    <?php do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user); ?>
    <p class="form-submit">
        <?php echo $referer; ?>
        <div>
        <button name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button"
                value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>">update</button>
        <?php //wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
    </p>            
    <!--a class="profileinfo-edit" id ="edit" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/my-profile">Update Profile</a-->
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where on the code your trying to redirect? what is going on here....

Comment: After an edit your code is now syntax hilighted - some of the commented out parts may be important.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference/profile_update

```
    add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

    function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    // Redirect
    $redirect_url = '/your-redirect/permalink';
    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit();

    }
```